# Yii2 Валидация чекбокса "пользовательское соглашение"

Tags: php, yii2, валидация, checkbox

Мне нужно провалидировать чекбокс с пользовательским соглашением

Попробовал вот так:

View:

```
    <label class="checkbox">
                <?php $form->field($model, 'privacy_conditions_acceptance', ['errorOptions' => ['tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'form-control-hint'], 'template' => "{input}"])->checkbox(['value' => 0, 'class' => 'privacy_checkbox', 'id' => '', 'name' => ''], false)->label(false)?>
                    <span class="mark"></span>
                </label>
```

SignupForm:

```
    [['privacy_conditions_acceptance'], 'required', 'message'=>'You must agree bla-bla-bla'],
```

Результат: валидатор не пропускает форму, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя переписывать атрибут 'name' у чекбокса, иначе он будет всегда записываться как null